# Why these strings are not translated by Qt 5

Tags: qt

I'm porting a Qt4 project to Qt5 (Qt 5.4.1 + VS2013), the project have some string translations. The source file is UTF-8 encoded. But today I found the piece of code won't work (They all worked well in Qt4).

```
this->paraList.push_back( QPair<QString,QString>( QString(tr("℃:")), QString(tr("Ω")) ) );
```

'paraList' is a QList, and the strings in it finally shown in a QTableWidget. They both show correctly in QLiguist, but when my application run, the centigrade symbol and the Ohm symbol don't be translated correctly, as below

[image]

But all other strings are translated correctly. My locale is zh_CN. Why these two characters are **so special**?

Comment: Are you sure that the font being used in your application supports those symbols?

Comment: is it possible that these translations are in a separated translation file ( `*.qm`)? if so, is that file loaded into the translator?

Comment: In Qt 5.4 + VS2013 it works for me. I think @TheDarkKnight is right, the problems with fonts.

Comment: @gomons: Yes, they all in one .qm file, and the font is OK. I get some informations on net, maybe the magic "#pragma execution_character_set("utf-8")", I'll try it. Have you noticed this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is encoding. You are using non ASCII characters as translation pattern. There was some change in Qt5 how c-strings are converted (I don't remember details) and I'm suspecting this might be a problem.

Try use [trUtf8](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject-obsolete.html#trUtf8) this should fix the problem.